# Are there any materials for the self-teaching of mathematical logic？

Tags: logic, learning-methods

I want to learn something about mathematical logic just for further analytical philosophy studying，then how far should I learn mathematical logic? Are there any study materials with great mathematical rigor about mathematical logic but demanding little elementary knowledge about algebra？ If all materials demand elementary knowledge about algebra，then are there any materials for the self-teaching of these elementary knowledge about algebra？

Comment: Peter Smith has published a teach-yourself guide to logic on this website: https://www.logicmatters.net/tyl/ On the same site, you will find his own text book, An Introduction to Formal Logic, which is available for free download.

Comment: Introduction To Metamathematics by Stephen Cole Kleene.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A first course in mathematical logic and set theory by Michael L O'Leary is excelent to start learning mathematical logic.